# How to check if a pdf file is open in and close it in c++

Tags: c++, shell, pdf

I want to move to a page in a pdf file in c++. I use shellExecute and it works fine. But if the file has been opened before, it will not go to destination page. I want to check if the file is open and close it before using shellExecute command. How can I do it and is there any better way?

Comment: I fail to see the C++ question here. For that matter I fail to see a shell question here. It might be related to PDF. Most probably this depends strongly on the particular PDF reader you're using. There are many.

Comment: what do you want to do with the PDF? Do you only want to check if the PDF is open? Or do you want to manipulate the PDF?

Comment: @ CML: just check if it is open

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
is_open()
```

to check if a file is opened or not. I think you have to include iostream and/or fstream. Not sure..

Maybe this question will help you: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094253/editing-pdf-with-xpdf-or-with-something-else)

Answer (score 0):

Use these lines of code

```
std::ifstream ifs ("test.pdf");

if (ifs.is_open()) {
  ifs.close();
}
```

Comment: I use it but the is_open always returns ture

Comment: `std::ifstream ifs ("test.pdf");`  will automatically open the file we specified as parameter.

Comment: so how can I check if a pdf file is open?

Comment: I think file stream will give some error if we are trying to open already opened file. you can catch it by adding try catch block.

Comment: I do your suggestion in this cod"